# How to install Chrome browser properly via command line?

Tags: linux

I have tried to install it using the command **sudo apt-get install chrome-browser**   on terminal but it's not working.

Comment: This '[link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79280/how-to-install-chrome-browser-properly-via-command-line)' may help you !

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution is to download the .deb file from the [official site](https://www.google.it/chrome/browser/desktop/) and install with `sudo dpkg -i filename` command. However you can install chromium with the command `sudo apt-get install chromium`.